# Looking for a British expression that is similar to "mind you" in meaning

Tags: expressions

language gurus!

I came across a British expression while reading op-eds on the Gurdian, which I forgot. It was similar to "mind you" in meaning as in the following sentence:

"They are expensive, mind you, but the quality of their craftsmanship is worth the extra price."

Cheers in advance!

Comment: “to be sure” “no question” “of course” “I’ll have you know” “Lord knows” ...

Comment: Isn't "mind you" used like that in British English?

Comment: @nnnnnn - yes it is.

Comment: This seems like either a very broad question, or one that only you can know the answer to.

Comment: Yeah, seems like my question was too broad, but I find all the comments really productive. Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1):

..."believe you me" is often used by some older folks in Kent, to my mind , it's an awfully old fashioned way to speak, mind you , Father always uses it but , to put things in perspective , he had a tough start due to the war, not to put too fine a point on it, Dad grew up a yokel .

Comment: Yes, I have relatives in Orpington, too.

Comment: So are we there with the answer yet?